# how to display netcdf raster values over map?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, geopandas, cartopy, weather

I'm trying to plot  netcdf raster values of snowfall data in a text format overlaying what I currently have (mentioned further below).  Example, something like this below:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgQ5Y.png)

This is all the relevant code I have so far.  I excluded the non relevant code.  I tried plt.text and it gave me "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

[What I have plotted so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9SvZ.png)

```
import numpy
from datetime import datetime
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import cartopy.mpl.ticker as cticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker, patheffects
from metpy.units import units
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter, maximum_filter, minimum_filter
import xarray as xr
from metpy.plots import USCOUNTIES
from gradient import Gradient
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.colors as col

#Open NOAA Snowfall dataset
ds = xr.open_dataset('sfav2_CONUS_2021093012_to_2022042512.nc')
ds

lat = ds.lat
lon = ds.lon
#converts snowfall data to inches
snowdata = ds['Data'] * 39


plt.text(lon, lat, snowdata, transform=datacrs)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a vectorized way of plotting text (plt.text or plt.annotated). So you'll have to loop over the arrays and plot each point.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as PathEffects
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(18, 9)
lons, lats = np.mgrid[-17:18:2, 8:-9:-2]

lons = lons * 10
lats = lats * 10

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5), dpi=86, facecolor="w", subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.EqualEarth()))

ax.pcolormesh(lons, lats, data, cmap="coolwarm", alpha=.2, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()

for val, lat, lon in zip(data.flat, lats.flat, lons.flat):
    
    ax.text(
        lon, lat, f"{val:1.1f}", ha="center", va="center", transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
        path_effects=[PathEffects.withStroke(linewidth=3, foreground="w", alpha=.5)],
    )
```

[image]